# Error Running MongoDB Script on OpenShift Gear

Tags: javascript, mongodb, openshift, mongodb-shell

I wrote a database population script (in JavaScript) so that I could easily run it on my local and on the server.  I want to run it from the command line so that all I have to do is push it to the server/gear and execute it.  The script runs fine on my local, but when I try to run it on the OpenShift gear it gives the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.XX.XXX.X:27017/admin
Sat Sep 12 12:20:25.979 count failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } 
at src/mongo/shell/query.js:180
failed to load: ./Create.js
```

I'm trying to execute the command:

```
[xxxxxx-xxxxxx.rhcloud.com scripts]\> mongo ./Create.js
```

I have included the innards of my file.  I left out all the document creation stuff.  Just know I added document to an array.

```
// Switch to the DB we want
var connection;
try {
    // Try to connect to local first
    connection = new Mongo();
}
catch(err) {
    // If error, connect to OpenShift server
    connection = new Mongo('127.XX.XXX.X:27017');
}

db = connection.getDB('xxxxxxx');

// Create array to store documents
var newDocs = [];

...
// Documents are added to newDocs here
...

// If any new documents exist, insert them
if(newDocs.length) {
    var bulk = db.xxxxxxx.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

    newDocs.forEach(function (doc) {
        bulk.insert(doc);
    });

    bulk.execute();
    print('NEW DOCS INSERTED');
}
else {
    print('NO NEW DOCS');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `db.auth('username', 'password');` to authenticate.  Ultimately, I added a variable to the script to track if I was running the script locally or on the server.  Then I used a variable for the password so that I wouldn't have the DB password just hanging out in the script.  I pass the password in from the command line with the `--eval` option.  Here is the altered head of the script:

```
// Switch to the DB we want
var connection;
var isLocal = true;
try {
    // Try to connect to local first
    connection = new Mongo();
}
catch(err) {
    // If error, connect to OpenShift server
    connection = new Mongo('127.XX.XXX.X:27017');
    isLocal = false;
}

db = connection.getDB('xxxxxxx');

if(!isLocal) {
    // If on server, authenticate
    db.auth('username', password);
}

// Create array to store documents
var newDocs = [];
```

Then, to run the script from the command line on the server, I use the following:

```
mongo --eval "var password = 'xxxxxxx';" Create.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing your username/password to connect to your mongodb database on openshift?  look at the error you got "unauthorized..."